# How to get all review filter/order by rating star of a product

Tags: magento-1.9, php-5.4

```
$productId = $my_product->getId();

$reviews = Mage::getModel('review/review')->getResourceCollection()
          ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
          ->addEntityFilter('product', $productId)
          ->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
          ->setDateOrder()
          ->addRateVotes();
```

Using this get all review & rating but want to get most rating star reviews

Comment: Can you please rephrase the last statement? It's not very clear what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 3):

This code will put reviews with higher rates on top:

```
$productId = $my_product->getId();
$reviews = Mage::getModel('review/review')->getResourceCollection()
          ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
          ->addEntityFilter('product', $productId)
          ->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
          ->setDateOrder()
          ->addRateVotes();

$reviews->getSelect()->joinInner(
    'rating_option_vote',
    'main_table.review_id = rating_option_vote.review_id',
    array('review_value' => 'rating_option_vote.value')
);
$reviews->getSelect()->order('review_value DESC');
```