# Magento review list sorting

Tags: magento-1.9, sorting, ratings, product-review

I need to apply sorting on Review list by Highest Rating and Lowest rating. I searched but not find any solution for that.

Can anyone has idea how can i apply sorting on **Highest Rating and Lowest rating on Review List**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: sorting means highest to lowest??

Comment: yes highest and lowest

Comment: highest and lowest? or  highest to lowest?

Comment: highest to lowest and lowest to highest

Comment: refer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/111094/45103